# DML in LWC Apex controller class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community

How does with and without sharing work in regards to Community users and DML in LWC Apex controllers. Testing without sharing on a community user that does not have CRUD access on the object throws an internal server error. Does with or without sharing not have any effect on DML in LWC controllers for Community users?

Apex class

```
public without sharing class myClass{
    
     @AuraEnabled
      public static void myMethod(Application__c application) {
        try {
          insert application;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    
    }
```

LWC method

```
handleSubmit() {
  processApplication({ application: this.application})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you check if [inherited sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) has any different behavior?

Comment: Inherited sharing does not help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Errors are notoriously difficult to troubleshoot. I would suggest submitting a support case with the ISE # to get more detail on what the root cause is.